How to build a CapacitorJS app for Anddroid 6 (SDK 23)?
I have a project that uses CapacitorJS v6 and I need to build it for android 6 (SDK level 23).
I changed the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23 in the variables.graddle file, but I got this error:
"In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above"
Since I need to compile this project using SDK 23 of android, I changed JDK version to 1.8 (Java 8). I changed it for all modules. Now I'm getting errors from Java code, like "'switch' expressions are not supported at language level '8'".
Does someone have any idea about how can I build this project for android 6?

Capacitor supports SDK 23 out of the box, you don’t have to change the targetSDK for that, what determines the minimum supported version is the minSDK, which for Capacitor 6 is 22.
In fact the targetSDK should be set to 34 as it’s a requirement for submitting the apps to Google play.
